# android acitvity flow

Tags: android, android-layout

i am developing an android app and this is one problem that i am facing:

my main menu will pass an intent of image uri to another activity where it will display the image on the second activity.

i process the intent to get the uri and convert it to the bitmap in the onStart() method(which i coded myself to override the super class method). 
**(is it correct to do so?)**

**and where should i set the image onto the image view on the activity?**

my problem is after processing the image, my app will forced closed. but if i remove the onStart() method, the second activity will come up with no error, but there will be no image to display(since i din process to display the image).

when i use Log.d() method to show where my program stop, it does shows that the program run till after i process the intent and get the bitmap(where my program ends at the moment).

here is the code of my onStrat() method:

```
    protected void onStart()
    {

        Bitmap newBitmap = null;

        Intent imageURI = getIntent();
        Log.d("HERE", "intent received");

        String imageLoc = imageURI.getExtras().getString("IMAGE_URI");
        Log.d("HERE", imageLoc);

        Uri imageLocation = Uri.parse(imageLoc);
        Log.d("HERE", "Uri reated");

        try 
        {
        newBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageLocation);
    } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

        catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        Log.d("HERE", "bitmap created");


}
```

i messed up something and finally found the solution. thanks for the async task info and it really did speed up my process.

thank you.

Comment: share the code where you are processing your bitmap and the way you are passing the image's uri to the second activity.

Comment: @Android-Developer here is my onStart() method. basically it is a copy and paste from here and there from what i googled.

Comment: i pass the uri as a string from the main menu to the second activity and process the string back into uri on the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

Process the intent and get the uri and display the image in onResume() and it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

> i process the intent to get the uri and convert it to the bitmap in
>   the onStart() method(which i coded myself to override the super class
>   method). (is it correct to do so?)

You should place any CPU intensive operations in a separate thread when creating your `Activity`. The most common way is to use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for processing bitmap. You should start it's execution in `onCreate()` method just after getting extra information from your `Intent`.

> and where should i set the image onto the image view on the activity?

IMO, the best place to do that - is [`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) method of `AsyncTask`